# How does the timeline_markers list work in Blender?

Tags: python, list, blender

I have the following code:

```
import bpy
import math
import random


Markers = []

for marker in bpy.context.scene.timeline_markers:
    frame = marker.frame
    Markers.extend([frame])

print('-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+')
print(Markers)
Markers = sorted(Markers)
print(Markers)
```

And when I execute it, it gives me two different output for the first print statement, before **Markers = sorted(Markers)** and after it.

That's the output:

> -+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ 
>   [33, 93, 151, 212, 265, 409, 640, 786, 524, 317] 
>   [33, 93, 151, 212, 265, 317, 409, 524, 640, 786]

When the cycle reads the items in timeline_markers haven't they to be in increasing order?

But, assuming it's not like this, how this work?

Comment: The list is sorted. And you assign to the same variable. That's why it's shows as different output. Actually what you trying to archive ?

Comment: No, I mean, shouldn't it be sorted by default?

Comment: No.. It's sorted after the execution of `Markers = sorted(Markers)`. You can check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assuming that the timeline_markers are stored as a sorted list, this is not the case. While they are presented to python as a common list/array, they are stored internally by blender as a linked list. If you trace the source code back you will find they use ListBase as defined in [DNA_listBase.h](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/makesdna/DNA_listBase.h) and implemented in [listbase.c](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/blenlib/intern/listbase.c).

While we think of markers as a sequence in an order matching the timeline, there is no real need or benefit to keeping them sorted. If you want to display the list of markers in frame order then you just need to sort them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Not problem with your code. The code works fine that's why it's shows like that. You are assign to the same variable that's why it's shows different output. When you execute `print(Markers)` it's giving the original result. After `Markers = sorted(Markers)` the list is modified. So assign to some other variable like this `Sorted_Markers = sorted(Markers)`

You can check the difference here.

```
In [1]: markers = [33, 93, 151, 212, 265, 409, 640, 786, 524, 317]
In [2]: print (markers)
[33, 93, 151, 212, 265, 409, 640, 786, 524, 317]
In [3]: sorted_marker = sorted(markers)
In [3]: print (markers)
[33, 93, 151, 212, 265, 409, 640, 786, 524, 317]
In [4]: print (sorted_marker)
[33, 93, 151, 212, 265, 317, 409, 524, 640, 786]
```